# is it possible to get a file from TFS into a local unmapped folder?

Tags: tfs

Looking at [the docs for tf get](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf.aspx) I think the answer is no. Still, I could be wrong. I'd like to have a file that's mapped to C:\Projects\MyProject\SQL\myScript.sql. I'd then like to run a batch file that gets several files (including that one) from the repository, puts them into a local temp folder, runs them, then deletes them.

It's the first part that's the issue: I think that TFS won't let you get files into a folder without remapping the source folder to point to that folder first.

So I suppose I need to remap the remote folder to point to a new local folder (C:\Temp\Scripts for instance) then get the files, then map the folder back to where it was. Seems like an extra step that helps nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [tf view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dxk6367.aspx) to see if that does what you need.  Otherwise, the usual pattern for doing stuff similar to this is to create a new workspace using the tf workspace command, map the folder, do a get then destroy the workspace.

Even better for you would probably to use the .NET API [VersionControlServer.DownloadFile()](http://VersionControlServer.DownloadFile()) - especially if you are doing his from a powershell script rather than a simple batch file.